# Update child entity / Attach entity to context

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I am creating a pre event plugin for CRM 2011 that sets the account owner and updates all the child contacts with the same owner.  The plugin is installed correctly and updates the main account record correctly but the child contact owner does not change .  I have pushed the owner name into another field of the contact to check I have the correct details and that field is updating.

I'm sure its something to do with attaching the child contacts to the correct context but so far I have drawn a blank.

```
//Set new account owner - Works fine
account.OwnerId = new EntityReference(SystemUser.EntityLogicalName, ownerId);

//Pass the same owner into the contacts - Does not get updated
UpdateContacts(account.Id, ownerId, service, tracingService);
```

The system is successfully updating the account owner and the description label of the child record.

```
public static void UpdateContacts(Guid parentCustomerId, Guid ownerId, IOrganizationService service, ITracingService tracingService)
    {
        // Create the FilterExpression.
        FilterExpression filter = new FilterExpression();

        // Set the properties of the filter.
        filter.FilterOperator = LogicalOperator.And;
        filter.AddCondition(new ConditionExpression("parentcustomerid", ConditionOperator.Equal, parentCustomerId));

        // Create the QueryExpression object.
        QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression();

        // Set the properties of the QueryExpression object.
        query.EntityName = Contact.EntityLogicalName;
        query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true);
        query.Criteria = filter;

        // Retrieve the contacts.
        EntityCollection results = service.RetrieveMultiple(query);
        tracingService.Trace("Results : " + results.Entities.Count);

        SystemUser systemUser = (SystemUser)service.Retrieve(SystemUser.EntityLogicalName, ownerId, new ColumnSet(true));
        tracingService.Trace("System User : " + systemUser.FullName);

        XrmServiceContext xrmServiceContext = new XrmServiceContext(service);

        for (int i = 0; i < results.Entities.Count; i++)
        {                
            Contact contact = (Contact)results.Entities[i];
            contact.OwnerId = new EntityReference(SystemUser.EntityLogicalName, systemUser.Id);
            contact.Description = systemUser.FullName;

            xrmServiceContext.Attach(contact);
            xrmServiceContext.UpdateObject(contact);
            xrmServiceContext.SaveChanges();

            tracingService.Trace("Updating : " + contact.FullName);
        }
    }
```

The tracing service prints out everything I would expect.  Do I need to also attach the system user and somehow attach the entity reference to the context?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to make a separate web service call using [AssignRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.crm.sdk.messages.assignrequest.aspx) to change the ownership of a record.  Unfortunately you cannot just change the Owner attribute.

Comment: Looks good. I will give it a go.  Just out of interest why is the process different for assigning an owner?  Is it not just a database relationship like any of the other joins?  Also is it correct to be adjusting child entities in a pre event, is this an acceptable practice?

Comment: Unfortunately this made no difference. I believe my issue is down to trying to change the owner of a child entity, setting the owner directly or using the AssignRequest work fine on the "Account" which is registered as the "Primary" entity but when I attempt to change owner for the child it just seems to be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

I think I was getting myself into all sorts of mess with this plugin as by default changing the account owner automatically changes the associated contacts owner.  I was therefore trying to overwrite something that it was already doing.

By using the AssignRequest to set the account owner rather than the child records it worked fine.  Credit given to Chris as he pointed me in the right direction.

All that was needed was to change the first line of my code to use AssignRequest and the entire UpdateContacts method became obselete.